# Keras - LSTM how to reshape input value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using LSTM with keras my testing and training is working fine but when i try to enter the different input i am getting error cannot reshape size 20 to `(1,20,30)`

this is my code for model.fit()

```
PositiveOrNegativeLabel=np.array([[1]])
PositiveOrNegativeLabel=PositiveOrNegativeLabel.reshape(1,-1)
PositiveOrNegativeLabel.shape
inputBatch =inputBatch.reshape(1,24,30)
testBatch =testBatch.reshape(1,24,30)
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(24,30)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(inputBatch,PositiveOrNegativeLabel,batch_size=24,epochs=9,verbose=1)
```

**my input is firstSentence array which is like this**

```
[  174 11501   420  4242 12111     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
```

**the shape of firstSentence is (20,)**

the kind of input which i have used to fit model

```
[[    0. 12184.   420.  4636.     0.  8840.     0.     0. 10499. 11508.
   7511.     0.  5468.  2879.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  6689.  2818. 12003.  6480.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.  3045. 11087.  2710.     0.   494.  1087.   420.  4995.
  11516.  3637.  5842.     0.  9963.  7015. 11090.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1287.   420.  4070. 11087.  7410. 12186.  2387. 12111.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.   494.     0.     0.  6541.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  8744. 11105.  1570.  5842.   174. 11266.  2929. 10438.  2879.
      0. 10936.  6330.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 11956.  5222.     0.     0. 12106.  6481.     0.  7093. 13756.
  12152.     0.     0.     0.     0. 10173.     0.  5173. 13756.  9371.
      0.  9956.     0.     0.  9716.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.   420.  5842.  3058. 11875.  2879.  1087. 11105.  4995.  8840.
      0. 11100. 11875.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  5419.   420.  2250.  1299.  2151. 12111.  6454.     0. 11501.
   8094.  5842.   942.  7503.  7410.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.   420.  5842.  3058. 11875.  2879.  1087. 11105.  4995.  8840.
      0. 11100. 11875.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1287.   420.  4070. 11087.  7410. 12186.  2387. 12111.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0. 11501.  1592. 10603. 11102.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.   174.  5842.  2387. 10453. 11090.     0.  7531. 11956.   450.
    420. 11516.  6693.  2624.  9963. 11992.  9322. 11090. 12106.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  7544.     0.  1709.   420. 10936.  5222.  5842. 10407.  6937.
  11329.  2937.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  1520.  1295.     0.  8396.  9322. 12715.     0.  5172.  7232.
  11266.     0. 11266.  2757.  4416. 12020. 12111.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  7544.     0.  1709.   420. 10936.  5222.  5842. 10407.  6937.
  11329.  2937.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.  9191.  5952.     0.     0. 11516.  9413.  3081.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0. 11516.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  3395.  1087. 11904.  7232.  8840. 10115.  4494. 11516.  7441.
   8535. 12106.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
 [    0.  9371. 10412.  2356.  5412. 11502.     0.  1087.   228.     0.
   2937. 11480. 10412.  5412.   420.  9435.  2937.   228.  1057.  9435.
  12111.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
```

The value error i am getting is like this

```
cannot reshape array of size 20 into shape (1,20,30)
```

**and I am running this code to predict it**

```
predict=model.predict(firstSentence, batch_size=24, verbose=1, steps=None)
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict_classes(firstSentence)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(predict)):
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (predict[i], ynew[i]))
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the `batch_size` with the number of timesteps. The `input_shape` to an LSTM layer should be `(num_timesteps, num_features)` and the batch size is inferred.  From what I can tell, your `num_timesteps` for training is 30 with 1 feature at each timestep. Your testing sentence only has 20 timesteps with 1 feature at each. This will cause compatability issues.

Comment: Based on my previous comment, I think `inputBatch` should have shape `(24, 30, 1)` and you will need to modify your target vector to have shape `(24, 1)`. Then, when making predictions, the shape of `firstSentence` should be `(1, 30, 1)`.  [This article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/) about input sizes to LSTMs in Keras is very helpful.

Comment: @caseWestern can you please make an answer for this so that i can accept it.

Comment: @caseWestern i tried to shape the FirstSentence to (1,30,1) also (1,20,1) not worked

Comment: Do you only have 1 training example as your labels suggest? Or is it 24 training examples, each of which has 30 timesteps with 1 feature at each timestep?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the `batch_size` with the number of timesteps. The `input_shape` to an LSTM layer in Keras should be (`num_timesteps, num_features)`. The `batch_size` is inferred based on the `batch_size` used in `fit`. From what I can tell, your training data has 24 examples, each with 30 timesteps that each have 1 feature.

Moreover, your code only had one label, but from what I can tell you have 24 examples and will therefore need 24 labels.

```
import numpy as np 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Need same number of labels as examples
PositiveOrNegativeLabel = np.ones(shape = (24, 1))
# 24 examples, each with 30 timesteps, 1 feature at each timestep
inputBatch = result.reshape(24, 30, 1)

model=Sequential()

# input_shape is (num_timesteps, num_features)
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(30, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(inputBatch, PositiveOrNegativeLabel,
          batch_size=24, epochs=9, verbose=1)
```

Your testing sentence only has a single example with 20 timesteps each of which has 1 feature. Therefore, you will need to pad the testing sentence with zeros.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# Need 30 timesteps
firstSentence = pad_sequences([firstSentence], maxlen = 30)[0]
firstSentence = firstSentence.reshape((1, 30, 1))

predict=model.predict(firstSentence, batch_size=1, verbose=1, steps=None)

# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict_classes(firstSentence)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(predict)):
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (predict[i], ynew[i]))
```

This code works, but I may have interpreted your set-up incorrectly. Thus, if you only have 1 training example as your training labels suggest, then the shape of the input batch should be `(1, 24, 30)` and your testing sequence will also need 24 timesteps with 30 features at each.

For more on shaping inputs to an LSTM in Keras, see [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/).